# How to freeze particular row / column in QTableWidget python?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, freeze, qtableview, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget generated by QTDesigner in which I want to,

1. freeze particular row (row 0,1,2)
2. freeze particular column (column 0)

How can I get this going?

EDIT: I think answer is available to implement in C++ but I am not able to make it work for python. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-frozencolumn-example.html

I tried looking over some threads on stack over flow and some other platforms but none of them has answer for python.

**Code Generated by Qtdesigner:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(428, 285)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 391, 231))
        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.AnyKeyPressed|QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked|QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.EditKeyPressed|QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectedClicked)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Age"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "City"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**My Script:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from demo import Ui_MainWindow

class DemoTable(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                 
    def __init__(self):
        super(DemoTable, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    demowindow = DemoTable()   
    demowindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "freeze"?

Comment: the way excel freezes the row and column, i want to do the same here. if top row is freezed, it does not go up when you scroll down &  same with column, if you freeze first column and scroll right, this column stays as is at bottom left.

Comment: Mmmh. What you ask can be done, but it's not easy to implement. Qt documentation gives a [solution for a frozen column](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-frozencolumn-example.html) (but it's provided for C++, so you'll need to reimplement it in Python), but doing that for rows also is much more difficult...

Comment: Thanks @musicamante but I am not much familiar with C++. if anyone reading this thread could help, it would be great!

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for an answer. [Here](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples/itemviews/frozencolumn) is a similar C++ code translated in python.

Answer (score 0):

*"the way excel freezes the row and column, i want to do the same here. if top row is freezed, it does not go up when you scroll down & same with column"*

This can be done with QTableWidget by using the "currentCellChanged" signal. .connect() it to a slot.

When the current cell is changed (to currentRow) use the QTableWidget.setRowHidden() method to hide the Previous row. Block signal, then manually setCurrentCell where you want it (likely after the hidden rpw). Unblock signal. Can also manipulate TableWidget to .ScrollToTop ...

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTableWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableWidget.currentCellChanged